# How to get Count of IGrouping<'a, Foo> Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am attempting to write a query that returns a list grouped by OrderID and DateTime value. My first query returns a grouped count which is of type:

```
IGrouping<'a, Foo> SomeList
```

Now I am attempting to execute a loop to produce a view model of type `List<ViewModel>` model based on the above. The problem is an `Order` may contain more than 1 item `OrderLines`, I wanted to add a check if the count is > 1 then loop through the sub items and create an object to add to the List object.

```
var query = (from o in db.Orders
             join ol in db.OrderLines on o.OrderID equals ol.OrderID
             join u in db.Users on o.UserSalesID equals u.UserID
             join r in db.Reports on o.UserSalesID equals r.UserId
             where o.Timestamp <= timeNow && o.Timestamp >= timeYesterday && u.UserID == o.UserSalesID
             group ol by new { o.Timestamp, o.OrderID } into g
             select g).ToList();
```

// the loop

```
foreach (var orderLineList in query)
{
    foreach (var item in orderLineList) // how to get a count of OrderLineList here
    {
        // check if count is more than 1 then create an annon object and get total price of order etc 
        // if not then carry on as normal

        model.Add(new ReportViewModel()
        {
            Gross = orderLineList.Sum(ol => ol.RetailPrice),
            Net = orderLineList.Sum(ol => ol.RetailPrice), // minus expense,
            PaymentType = orders.Where(o => o.OrderID == item.OrderID).FirstOrDefault().PaymentID,
            Quantity = db.OrderLines.Where(ol => ol.OrderID == item.OrderID).Sum(ol => ol.Quantity),
            OrderID = item.OrderID
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. However, the count of the group is just `orderLineList.Count()`

Comment: OrderlineList is of type IGrouping<'a,Foo>, where 'a is in an annoymous type. In the intelliSense I get a .Count<Tsource> so how to get a count?

Comment: That's not a problem, `Count<TSource>()` is the generic version of `Count`

Comment: oh I am being so silly! - aha of course in a for loop it will not work, yikes thanks! lol, it is because 'int' does not contain a definition for a GetEnumerator!

Comment: By the way, you are calling the database inside your inner for loop which is horribly inefficient, especially when it looks like you already have that information in your query.

Comment: point noted, yes you are right - at the moment I am building the query as my linq skills are not great will finesse it once I can get the result set I am after :)

Comment: Also, I'm guessing that the inner loop isn't doing what you really want which is maybe why you're asking about the count. Are you just trying to get a summary of orders with their respective quantites and prices or do you want a record for every order item?

Comment: so a summary of orders with their respective quantities and prices grouped by date and order id

Comment: Why is your `Quantity` shown as calculated from `OrderID` only, and not for the date ?

Comment: Because the orderlines table does not have a date column. That column exists in the Order table.